# No video output running on QEMU

Tags: raspbian-lite, qemu, framebuffer

I have been trying to set up a RPi 3b emulation on QEMU for testing software related to the framebuffer, and have got it working including networking, but not video.

Doing `ls /dev/`, I can't find the framebuffer, but QEMU detects the bcm2835-fb. Is there something wrong with my OS or my setup? Am I just missing a step? How could I fix this?

The command I'm currently using is:

```
sudo qemu-system-aarch64 \
    -M raspi3b \
    -append "rw earlyprintk loglevel=8 console=ttyAMA0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootdelay=1" \
    -dtb bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb \
    -sd 2022-01-28-raspios-bullseye-armhf-lite.img \
    -kernel kernel8.img \
    -m 1G \
    -smp 4 \
    -usb -device usb-mouse -device usb-kbd \
    -device usb-net,netdev=net0 \
    -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently (march 2022), QEMU's framebuffer isn't compatible with the most recent RPi linux kernel, so the solution right now is to just use an older version of raspios. Buster with linux-4.19 works for me.